# Detect if Windows device is locked while running as Local System account

Tags: c++, winapi

Is is usually possible to check if a desktop is locked by using the [SHQueryUserNotificationState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shqueryusernotificationstate) API, but when running as LocalSystem, the state is not correctly detected.

Is anyone aware of any workarounds or alternative APIs that could be used to detect if the device is locked?

Comment: That's because Windows support multiple concurrent desktops (users).  Which desktop is locked depends on the user of the desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SHQueryUserNotificationState()` queries the state of the desktop session of the calling user.  But multiple users can be logged in at a time.  So you will have to query the specific user session you are interested in.

You can use [`WTEnumerateSessions()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsenumeratesessionsw) to see which user sessions are running, and then use [`WTSQuerySessionInformation(WTSSessionInfoEx)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsquerysessioninformationw) to query the desired user session for its [`WTSINFOEX_LEVEL1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/ns-wtsapi32-wtsinfoex_level1_w) session info, which has a `SessionFlags` member that will be set to `WTS_SESSIONSTATE_LOCK` if the session is locked.

Alternatively, you can have your app track session locks/unlocks in real-time by listening for [`WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/wm-wtssession-change) messages from [`WTSRegisterSessionNotification()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsregistersessionnotification).  Or, you can write a separate background service that listens for `SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE` notifications and then notifies your main app as needed via an IPC mechanism of you choosing.

Comment: Thank you very much Remy! WTSQuerySessionInformation() works well.